# Trying to download string and can't search in it context

Tags: c#, html, .net, webclient

I am using WebClient to download string html from WebSite and then i am trying to manipulate the string by using SubString and IndexOf..

Also some times i use the functions: substring, indexOf or contains and a strange thing happens:
Some times it shows a text (HTML code) and some times it isn't show anything at all.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.google.com");
        }
```

This is my code for getting an html code from a web site.
Now for example in this site i want to get the source of an image - a specific img (or another attribute)

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(htmlCode))
        {
            string inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (inputLine.Contains("img"))
                {
                   RichTextBox.Text += inputLine;
                }
             }
        }
```

There May be some syntax problems but don't look at it, They are not important.

Do you have an alterenetive or better way to get an HTML source code from a page and handle with it. It has to be HTTPS site and i would like a good explanation of it.

Sorry for noob question.

Comment: "There May be some syntax problems but don't look at it, They are not important." What makes you think that? Why would they not be important? What do you mean by "some times it shows a text" - what does? Have you tried debugging through it? Your question is really unclear...

Comment: This is not the original code and this is why it may contain some syntax problems. 
The strange thing with the code is that some times it show a text in the text box and sometimes it just skips the IF and does nothing. it does download the string but it seems like it is not handling with it normally all the time.

Comment: from what i understood from the question, it seems you can assist http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to parse that incoming HTML

Comment: "This is not the original code and this is why it may contain some syntax problems" So what you're saying is that it's entirely possible that the problem is in code we can't see. That makes it hard to help you. This is why you should post a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: also sometimes when i use substring and index of it can show me different text every time i load the debbug. Very stange .. and i can't understand whether it because of the webclient or maybe something else.